# AWS javascript SDK request.js send request function execution time gradually increases

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis

I am using aws-sdk to push data to Kinesis stream.
I am using PutRecord to achieve realtime data push.
I am observing same delay in putRecords as well in case of batch write.
I have tried out this with 4 records where I am not crossing any shard limit.

Below is my node js http agent configurations. Default maxSocket value is set to infinity.

```
 Agent {
  domain: null,
  _events: { free: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  defaultPort: 80,
  protocol: 'http:',
  options: { path: null },
  requests: {},
  sockets: {},
  freeSockets: {},
  keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
  keepAlive: false,
  maxSockets: Infinity,
  maxFreeSockets: 256 }
```

Below is my code.

I am using following code to trigger putRecord call

```
    event.Records.forEach(function(record) {
    var payload = new Buffer(record.kinesis.data, 'base64').toString('ascii');
     // put record request
     evt = transformEvent(payload );
     promises.push(writeRecordToKinesis(kinesis, streamName, evt ));
}
```

Event structure is

```
evt = {
          Data: new Buffer(JSON.stringify(payload)),
          PartitionKey: payload.PartitionKey,
          StreamName: streamName,
          SequenceNumberForOrdering: dateInMillis.toString()
        };
```

This event is used in put request.

```
function writeRecordToKinesis(kinesis, streamName, evt ) {
  console.time('WRITE_TO_KINESIS_EXECUTION_TIME');
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  try {
    kinesis.putRecord(evt , function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.warn('Kinesis putRecord %j', err);
        deferred.reject(err);
      } else {
          console.log(data);
        deferred.resolve(data);
      }
      console.timeEnd('WRITE_TO_KINESIS_EXECUTION_TIME');
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error occured while writing data to Kinesis' + e);
    deferred.reject(e);
  }
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Below is output for 3 messages.

```
WRITE_TO_KINESIS_EXECUTION_TIME: 2026ms
WRITE_TO_KINESIS_EXECUTION_TIME: 2971ms
WRITE_TO_KINESIS_EXECUTION_TIME: 3458ms
```

Here we can see gradual increase in response time and function execution time.

I have added counters in aws-sdk request.js class. I can see same pattern in there as well.

Below is code snippet for aws-sdk request.js class which executes put request.

```
 send: function send(callback) {
console.time('SEND_REQUEST_TO_KINESIS_EXECUTION_TIME');
if (callback) {
  this.on('complete', function (resp) {
    console.timeEnd('SEND_REQUEST_TO_KINESIS_EXECUTION_TIME');
    callback.call(resp, resp.error, resp.data);
  });
}
this.runTo();

return this.response;
```

},

Output for send request:

```
SEND_REQUEST_TO_KINESIS_EXECUTION_TIME: 1751ms
SEND_REQUEST_TO_KINESIS_EXECUTION_TIME: 1816ms
SEND_REQUEST_TO_KINESIS_EXECUTION_TIME: 2761ms
SEND_REQUEST_TO_KINESIS_EXECUTION_TIME: 3248ms
```

Here you can see it is increasing gradually.

Can anyone please suggest how can I reduce this delay?
3 seconds to push single record to Kinesis is not at all acceptable.

Comment: Where are you running this code? on your local machine? in AWS? in the same region?